# Code doesn't run

Tags: python

When i try to run my code all i get is this:

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
 RESTART: C:/Users/Owner/Documents/School Work/Computer Science/Python/Coding Practise/Fruit Machine.py 
>>>
```

it doesnt run, it just tells me where my file is saved... please help.

Comment: Please post your code, as that may help us understand your problem.

Comment: Try renaming your `Fruit Machine.py` script as `Fruit_Machine.py`

Comment: How are you trying to run the code? Post the full command.

Comment: Since you haven't edited the question or replied to comments, I assume the problem is fixed. Please either post your solution as an answer, mark the answer as correct if it fixed your problem, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your code is running properly, but nothing in your code is outputting anything (i.e. you haven't put any `print`s or `input`s). So your code is running as programmed, but if you're expecting something to be printed, you need to use the `print` and `input` statements.